# How do I install a new control panel theme?

Tags: cp-themes

I can't get the themes to work, it just shows "default" in the theme drop-down box. Have coppied everything into the right places in my EE installation, apart from the asset folder, no idea where that is supposed to go. Can anybody shed any light on this at all please? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Control panel themes are installed in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT/themes/third_party` directory. After placing the theme in there, you should see it in the list in the control panel general preferences.

Comment: Sorry, when I posted the question I was on the page for 
ThEEditorCodeMirror, that's where I can't get themses to work.

Comment: Instructions for changing themes with that add-on are in one of the support forum posts: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/theeditorcodemirror/viewthread/5112

Comment: Thank you, did everything according to instructions, dropdown list now shows the themes, but doesn't change appearance, everything still looks like the Standard EE layout. Must be overlooking something else... :-(